# Retain range values after from submission and page loads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on price range slider. When a user is selecting price range, I am submitting the form on change of price range slider. But the slider values are getting reset after the form is submitted and page load. Below is the code -

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="price-slider">
           <span><label for="">Price from</label>
           <input readonly name="priceFrom" id="priceFrom" type="number" value="200000" min="200000" max="1000000"/>
           <label for="">Price to</label>
           <input readonly name="priceTo" id="priceTo" type="number" value="1000000" min="200000" max="1000000"/></span>
           <input value="200000" min="200000" max="1000000" step="500" type="range"/>
            <input value="300000" min="300000" max="1000000" step="500" type="range"/>
       </div>
</div>
```

The code to submit form on price range slider is -

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('input[type=range]').change(function() {
      $("form#search-form").submit();
   });
});
</script>
```

Is there any way I can retain the user selected range values after form submission and page load? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will point you in the right direction. https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/jC9ms/  and this http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/ReT8n/

Comment: @pendo. Can you provide any input?