# Form submit on change of a both price ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit the form when both the range value changes. The code structure is -

```
<div class="card price-range-div">
   <div class="card-header">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Search By Budget</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="price-slider">
            <span>
                  <label for="">Price from</label>
                  <input readonly name="priceFrom" id="priceFrom" type="number" value="200000" min="200000" max="1000000"/>
                  <label for="">Price to</label>
                  <input readonly name="priceTo" id="priceTo" type="number" value="1000000" min="200000" max="1000000"/>
            </span>
            <input id="first-input" value="200000" min="200000" max="1000000" step="500" type="range">
            <input id="second-input" value="300000" min="300000" max="1000000" step="500" type="range">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have given unique ID's to input field as 'first-input' and 'second-input'. I want to submit form only if two of these range value changes. May be using if and && condition in jquery. But i am not sure how to do this. Currently, I am able to submit form only on one input ie. 'first-input' change. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$('input#first-input').change(function() {
    $('form#search-form').submit(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to understand and implement this is to create a variable that tracks the status of each input.  Once both of those variables have been 'changed', then you know you should immediately submit the form.  The solution would not scale well to dozens of inputs, but will certainly work for 2.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card price-range-div">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Search By Budget</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="price-slider">
            <span>
                    <label for="">Price from</label>
                    <input readonly name="priceFrom" id="priceFrom" type="number" value="200000" min="200000" max="1000000"/>
                    <label for="">Price to</label>
                    <input readonly name="priceTo" id="priceTo" type="number" value="1000000" min="200000" max="1000000"/>
            </span>
            <input id="first-input" class="trackedInputs" value="200000" min="200000" max="1000000" step="500" type="range">
            <input id="second-input" class="trackedInputs" value="300000" min="300000" max="1000000" step="500" type="range">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    //create variables to track a value change
    input1Changed = false;
    input2Changed = false;
    //fire our handler, whenever one of the two inputs changes
    $("input#first-input").change(function() {
        input1Changed = true;
        if(input1Changed && input2Changed) {
            alert("Submit the form here!");
        }
    });
    $("input#second-input").change(function() {
        input2Changed = true;
        if(input1Changed && input2Changed) {
            alert("Submit the form here!");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Pendo. Appreciate it mate. Can you please help me to retain the price range values after submitting form and page loads??? If possible?

Comment: This was the question I have asked to retain slider range values after form submission and page loading - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547898/retain-range-values-after-from-submission-and-page-loads

Comment: I'll check that out.  If my answer helped, please mark it as the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Done @pendo. Thank you.